# Code for sending message hello world to sqs when object is added to s3 bucket in cdk typescript

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs, aws-cdk

```
import sqs = require('@aws-cdk/aws-sqs');
import s3 = require('@aws-cdk/aws-s3');
import s3n = require('@aws-cdk/aws-s3-notifications');
import { Construct } from '@aws-cdk/core';

export class SendMessageStack extends Construct {

    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string) {
        super(scope, id);

        // Create an S3 bucket 
        const bucket=new s3.Bucket(this, 'bucket'

        const queue=new sqs.Queue(this, 'queue', {
       visibilityTimeout:     cdk.Duration.seconds(300)
  });

 // Add an event notification to the bucket to send messages to the queue
     bucket.addEventNotification(s3n.EventType.OBJECT_CREATED, 
                            new s3n.SqsDestination(queue));

 // Create a sqs message with content body “Hello World”
 const message = {
    contentBody: "Hello world",
} ;

// To send a message
queue.send(message);
```

}
}

1. I want to send a message “hello” to sqs when object is added to s3 bucket.
   But it is showing error in last line” queue.send(message)
   Error- property does not exist on type queue.

How to resolve the error?
Is there any method by which we can send message “hello” or some other text to sqs when object is added to s3 bucket in cdk type script

- I tried the above method.

Comment: In your question you have mixed multiple contexts. One is sending messages to SQS which is done with the aws-sdk. The other one is provisioning AWS infrastructure with AWS CDK. You can't do it at once

Comment: That mean we can’t use Aws cdk and sdk at same time ?
And if I wanted to create a cdk lamba in typescript and then writing my lambda handler code in java, so for lambda handler code can we use Aws sdk ?  

And can you tell why we use Aws sdk ?

I’m new to NAWS and struggling with this. Thankyou for your help.

Comment: You can, but by the time your script executes your infrastructure is not ready. Hence you can run skript with aws-sdk after the cdk deployment has been done

Answer (score 0):

This is not how CDK, S3 or SQS works.

S3 does not support sending arbitrary messages via SQS.
And if you declare a message to be sent via CDK this happens ONCE, when you deploy the stack (and maybe whenever you update), but certainly not every time a object is put into the bucket.

Instead you need to set up a Lambda that listens to the original notification from S3. And then put code into that lambda that actually sends whatever message you want to wherever you want.